# Java method undefined

Tags: java, constructor, package

Currently following a video tutorial I got online, followed it to the last spacing and still got "The method setName(String) is undefined for the type Person".
What did I do wrong?

PS. I did it on a scrapbook page, imported the class from the package.

```
package org.totalbeginner.tutorial;

public class Person {
    // fields
    private String name; // name of the person
    private int maximumBooks; // Most books person can checkout

    // constructors
    public Person() {
        name = "unknown name";
        maximumBooks = 3;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String anyName) {
        name = anyName; 
    }

    public int getMaximumBooks() {
        return maximumBooks;
    }

    public void setMaximumBooks(int maximumBooks) {
        this.maximumBooks = maximumBooks;
    }

}
```

PS. This one below is from Myscrapbook

```
Person p = new Person();
p.setName("Fred");
p
```

Comment: What do you mean "did it in a scrapbook"?   Are you putting the above text in a file on a filesystem called Person.java and compiling it with javac?   Or something else?

Comment: Use eclipse. Create java project. create your above class in eclipse java project. you will automatically pointed to problem areas with tentative solutions.

Comment: Are there any more Person classes in your project? Also what is your file structure and how are you compiling your classes?

Comment: looks fine to me, I think you just need to have your IDE re-compile it, aka clean or build it.

Comment: @Sinon Post the Stack trace or complete error message that you are getting. And yeah, what is this "scrapbook page" thing?

Comment: Hi sorry for the lack of information.
I am using eclipse, for the definition of scrapbook page.
http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-create_scrapbook_page.htm

Comment: @everyone, hey guys I solved it somehow while recompiling. Thanks for the help! Greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're importing the correct package?
Make sure to include this in your imports:

```
import org.totalbeginner.tutorial.Person;
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the Person file and then try again. It should work then XD